# R: Code a For loop to read.csv() into multiple data.frames() that are given object names equal to their individual *.csv file names

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

So, I've been trying to code this for a while, but it looks like R keeps trying to read.csv into a single data.frame because it keeps returning a 'duplicate row' error. I need each *.csv to be read into a dataframe as its own object. Samples of code I've tried will be below; the first example is the piece of code (or something close to it) that I want to actually implement. Second example is a crude way I tried to recode the same function.

```
#First Example
annual.file.names = list.files(pattern = '* Balance Sheet.csv')
balance.sheet.read = function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    x[i] = data.frame(read.csv(file = x[i], header = T, row.names = 1, skip 
    = 1, blank.lines.skip = T)) #Name assignment needs fixing
  }
}
balance.sheet.read(annual.file.names) #Duplicate row names error
lapply(annual.file.names, balance.sheet.read)#Duplicate row names error



#Second Example
annual.file.names = list.files(pattern = '* Balance Sheet.csv')
balance.sheet.names = function(x){paste0("'", annual.file.names, "'", ",", 
    collapse = '')} #Copy/Paste below
b.sheet.names = c('names; removed in this example; format = *.csv')
b.sheet.file.namer = function(x) { for (i in 1:length(x)){ 
    return(as.character(b.sheet.names[i]))}}
b.sheet.file.names = b.sheet.file.namer(b.sheet.names)
lapply(b.sheet.names, (map_df(as.list(b.sheet.names), (read.csv(file = 
    b.sheet.file.names , header = T, row.names = 1, skip = 1, 
    blank.lines.skip = T)))))
     #Map_df is from Purrr package 
     #Invalid description error
     #sapply also doesn't work

#Extra Samples
balance.sheet.read(b.sheet.names)#Duplicate row names error
lapply(b.sheet.file.names,balance.sheet.read)#Duplicate row names error
sapply(b.sheet.file.names,balance.sheet.read)#Duplicate row names error
```

Answer (score 1):

`annual.file.names <- list.files(pattern = '* Balance Sheet.csv')
listDFs <- lapply(annual.file.names, read.csv)
combDFs <- do.call("rbind", listDFs)`

You can read in each file into a list of data.frames and then use `do.call` to bind the dataframes together and create a combined data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `list.files()` this will give you a vector with filenames as elements. So the problem in your first example seem to be that you are trying to coerce (read) your file `x[1]` into a character vector. Instead you can just loop through your filenames and read them one by one into a new data.frame, say `x1`, `x2` etc by using `assign()`

You can try something like this:

```
annual.file.names = list.files(pattern = '* Balance Sheet.csv')
for (i in 1:length(annual.file.names)){
   assign(paste0("x",i), read.csv(file = annual.file.names[i], header = T, row.names = 1, skip = 1, blank.lines.skip = T))
}
```

EDIT:

To have the filename as the new dataframe names:

```
annual.file.names = list.files(pattern = '* Balance Sheet.csv')
for (i in 1:length(annual.file.names)){
   assign(annual.file.names[i], read.csv(file = annual.file.names[i], header = T, row.names = 1, skip = 1, blank.lines.skip = T))
}
```

or if you want only the filename without `.csv`:

```
assign(gsub(".csv","",annual.file.names[i]), read.csv(file = annual.file.names[i], header = T, row.names = 1, skip = 1, blank.lines.skip = T))
```

Comment: Still getting a duplicate row error, though I took your advice and wrote this much cleaner piece for the reading portion. However, I am also getting duplicate row.name errors with this                                                                  
                                                                                                         `absd = function(x){ 
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {assign(i,data.frame(read.csv(file = x, header = T, row.names = 1, skip = 1, blank.lines.skip = T)))}}
lapply(annual.file.names,absd)`

Comment: I am not sure why you are using the `lapply`. The `for-loop` alone will read your files, no need for extra function

Comment: I think I missed the point where you wanted to have the file-names as the name of the individual dataframes. I will update my answer accordingly